# How to send Queries from Server and receive echo from client using Telnet libraries

Tags: c++, c, telnet

I have written a socket program wherein the client sends Telnet negotiations stored in char buffers to the server. The server receives it and responds with the message length of each buffer.Here is the code :

Server.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void error(char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
socklen_t clilen;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n;

if (argc < 2)
{
fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
exit(1);
}

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0)
{
perror("ERROR opening socket");
exit(1);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = atoi(argv[1]);

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
perror("ERROR on binding");
exit(1);
}

    if(listen(sockfd,5)<0)
     {
       perror("Error on listen");
     }
       while(1)
      {
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
     perror("ERROR on accept");
     exit(1);
    }

    //fork to hande this client
       if (fork() == 0)
       {  // client code no longer need this;
         close(sockfd);
          // loop until a closed or error state happens
         ssize_t n =0;
         while ((n = read(newsockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1))>0)
         {
           printf("Recieved : %*s\n",static_cast<int>(n),buffer);

           //send response
           static const char resp[] = "I got yout message \n";

           n = write(newsockfd, resp , sizeof(resp)-1);
           if(n<0)
            {
             perror("Error writing to socket ");
             exit(1);
            }
          }
      close(newsockfd);
      exit(0);
   }
    close(newsockfd); }
return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>


char buf1[] = {0xff, 0xfb, 0x18, 0xff, 0xfb, 0x1f};                  


void read (int sock)
{
    char buffer[256];

    /* Now read server response */
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int n = recv( sock, buffer, 255, 0 );
    if (n < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR reading from socket");
         return;
    }
    printf("\n%d bytes received buffer is: %s", n, buffer);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         printf("%2x ", buffer[i]);//printing ascii characters
    printf("\n");
}

void mwrite (int sock, char * buf, int size)
{
    int n = send( sock, buf, size, 0 );
    if (n < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR writing to socket");
         return;
    }
    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", n);
  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;


    char buffer[256];

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    /* Create a socket point */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        return(1);
    }
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL)
    {fprintf(stderr,"ERROR no such host \n");
     exit(0);}




    bzero((char *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);


    serv_addr.sin_port = htons( portno );

    /* Now connect to the server */
    if (connect( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) ) < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR connecting");
         return(1);
    }   



n= write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if(n<0)
    printf("ERROR writing in socket %d  len %d", n, strlen(buffer));


n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    if(n<0)
    perror("ERROR reading from socket");

printf("%s\n",buffer);





    bzero(buffer,256);
    buffer[0] = 0x0d;
    buffer[1] = 0x0a;

    printf("\nSend buff....");
    mwrite ( sockfd, buffer,2);
    read(sockfd);

    mwrite( sockfd, buf1, sizeof(buf1));
    printf("\nSend buff1....");
    read(sockfd);


    printf("\nRecieved all negotiation  buffers");

    close(sockfd); // close socket

    return 0;
```

Output is :
Client output :

```
debian:~/echoserver$ ./client 127.0.0.1 8088
I got your message 

Send buff....Bytes Sent: 2

20 bytes received buffer is: I got yout message 
49 20 67 6f 74 20 79 6f 75 74 20 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 20  a

Send buf1....Bytes Sent: 6

20 bytes received buffer is: I got yout message 
49 20 67 6f 74 20 79 6f 75 74 20 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 20  a 
Recieved all negotiation  buffers
```

Server output:

```
@debian:~/echoserver$ ./server 8088
Recieved : .N=�� 
Recieved : 
=��
```

I would also like to know if we want to reverse the process, that is ,send a 3 byte query sequence from server to client, where byte1-Interpret as command(0xff) , byte2-command code , byte3 - option code. Telnet is streamed so a received message may contain one or more queries. For example, the server sends a 3 byte message upon accepting connection (ff , fd , 18 ). The client should just echo back with Won't(ff , fc , 18)

Eg:

```
Server : Sending Query 1 : 0xff,0xfd,0x18
Client echo : 0xff , 0xfc , 0x18
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for [reducing the example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26182019/3)

Comment: `static_cast<int>(n)`   Hmmm, maybe add `C++` tag.

Comment: @chux i want my server to send a query (or multiple queries) to client, for which the client should echo with a don't or won't. How to proceed with this

Answer (score 1):

Your `buf` arrays are not strings (no terminating `'\0'` character), but you call `strlen()` on them. That will give you undefined behavior. Since they are binary arrays, use `sizeof` instead.

This is clearly visible in your own trace `printf()`s, the first line says "`Bytes Sent: 18`" but clearly `buf1` has only 6 bytes in it.

Answer (score 0):

In client.cpp, `buffer` is not initialized before its first use.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buffer[256]; 
  ...
  n= write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
```

When receiving a "string" from a socket, eithe append a trialing `'\0'` or insure the sender hase sent it.

```
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
... 
n = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof buf - 1);
if (n > 0 && buffer[n-1] != '\0') {
  buffer[n-1] = '\0';
  n++;
}
```

---

Function signature do not line up in `client.cpp`, so even though this is tagged `C`, this is a `C++` post.

```
void read (int sock) { ... }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ...
  n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
```